# Why is my Javascript running slow?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone advise on why my JS might be running super slow?

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
$(window).scroll( function(){

    /* Check the location of each desired element */
    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

        }

    }); 

});

});
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners

Comment: `Can anyone advise on why my JS might be running super slow? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?` - Those questions are off-topic as they are **primarily opinion-based** - *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.* - See what Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for more details.

Comment: @Nope Please don't use backticks to mark quotations, instead use *italics*. Backticks are for marking `code`.

Comment: Yasin Mahmood, having said that, maybe your question could be asked on [**https://codereview.stackexchange.com/**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - There, I think, you might get better feedback.

Comment: I would try to find out which exact call is taking the time using prints or smth.

Comment: The scroll event will be fired constantly, and then your constantly animating the opacity for half a seconds, indeed this will go super slow.  2 options, naggle the scroll, or at least cancel the last animation before starting the next.

Comment: @Nope  for general performance enhancements after bugs have been found, I'd agree.  But in this case I'd say it's more a bug.  So the question is totally relevant here.

Comment: @Keith The code might be slow because of a bug but that is not what is being asked here. However, if you are saying the question is asking for debugging help then it also off-topic as the question doesn't specify the desired behavior or a specific problem or error.

Comment: @Nope he's asking for help,. I'm not sure it matters how he expresses this.  If this question was about micro optimisations, then I'd say `primarily opinion-based`, but in this case it's a proper design error / bug.

Comment: @Keith Please see off-topic reasons when closing a question that state what is needed when asking for debugging help. It matters **a lot** how it is expressed and need **specifics** when doing so. - This question literally posts code, saying it's slow, help me to improve it. If you know why it is slow for a fact, post an answer instead.

Comment: @Nope  I think you missing my point, yes the OP could have done better, creating a working snippet, etc etc. But the problem can easily been seen here.   If your not willing to help the OP, fair enough.  And like I said, this is NOT an opinion-based problem, it's a bug, and from what I can remember helping people with bugs is not OT.

Comment: @Keith I referred OP to a site that could help as IMHO it fits there better. I fail to see how you trying to convince me of agreeing with you is helping the OP.  You don't have to agree with me but you can **not** vote to close the question or post a solution yourself, I'm not stopping you doing that. Arguing with me is pointless and achieves nothing to help OP. - Again, feel free to help OP debug his code. You don't need me to agree with you to do that!

Comment: @Nope  `Arguing with me is pointless`  You do know that works both way right?.. So it's one of those agree to disagree.  IMO: codereview is better when bugs are fixed, but that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Keith I'm glad you came to your senses. It seems to have helped OP a lot.

Comment: @Nope  I answered with 2 options for the OP, we have yet to wait to see if that helps, if the OP needs more clarification I'm sure he will ask..  Maybe your codereview link might help, who knows.  But it's nice to see such nice people on SO, it's so nice.  None of those flippant remarks you might get other places.

Answer (score -2):

I couldn't help but notice how you make unecessary calls to `$()` to reference `this` and `window`. Here's a minor performance suggestion:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var $el = $(this),
            $window = $(window),
            bottom_of_object = $el.offset().top + $el.outerHeight(),
            bottom_of_window = $window.scrollTop() + $window.height();
            
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object )
           $el.animate({'opacity':'1'},500);

    }); 

});

});
```